# How to fix "Direct use of $_SERVER Superglobal detected' in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, session, global-variable

Using the $_SERVER super global in an extension causes the following guideline error

```
Direct use of $_SERVER Superglobal detected
```

I know the alternative for Magento 2 but how do you solve this for Magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable globally, you can use session in magento1.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$session->setData("your_variable", "your value");

// Now you can retrieve your data elsewhere or even after the next request:
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$yourVariable = $session->getData("your_variable");
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant server variables like "SERVER_SOFTWARE.